The L screw of the front derailleur on my Canyon CF 7 (Shimano 105 groupset) is overtightened
could you please tell me how bad is it? and how can I fix it?


Nothing is broken. The screw is under pressure.

What is stopping you from backing out the screw?  Does it feel like it will strip ?

@Criggie it looks like the adjuster grubscrew has been pushed all the way through. It is not pretty. Maybe it can be fixed easily, maybe not but I think it will have to come off the bike and have the spring pressure held back somehow to make any progress.
